# Is it possible to do this using java on android?

Tags: java, android

How can I include this code snippet within each activity without explicitly copy and pasting the code in each activity? For example can I just place it in one place and all other activities would Reference this piece of code?

```
            @Override   
            public boolean dispatchTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) { 
                    // do something   

                    return super.dispatchTouchEvent(event);      

                }
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can put it in a base class that extends Activity and then extend all other activity classes from that.

```
public class MyActivity extends BaseActivity {
    // Your activity code    
}

public class BaseActivity extends Activity {
    @Override   
    public boolean dispatchTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) { 
        // do something   

        return super.dispatchTouchEvent(event);      
    }
}
```

Comment: is there a way to add stuff to the class itself because i dont want to go and change all the activity class names to my extended class

Comment: You don't have to change the class names, but you will have to change the `extends` clause on each of them to point to the base class instead of `Activity`. There's no away around that.